# Multiple fibres of an elliptic fibration on Enriques surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an Enriques surface and $f\colon X\to \Bbb{P}^1$ an elliptic fibration. I will denote by $F$ the general fibre and by $r_1F_1,\cdots,r_kF_k$ the multiple fibres of the fibration. I wanted to prove as an exercise that
$$k=2 , \quad r_1=r_2=2$$

Here is what I tried. By the canonical bundle formula
$$K_X\sim -F+\sum(r_i-1)F_i$$
and since $2K_X\sim0$ this yields $2F\sim\sum(2r_i-2)F_i=kF-2\sum F_i$, thus
$$(k-2)F\sim 2\sum F_i$$
but here I get stucked. Why should $\sum F_i$ be zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiplicities satisfy 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k \left(1- \frac{1}{r_i}\right) = 1
$$
then $k=r_1=r_2=2$.

Actually, if $q(X)=0$ then tghe plurigenus is:
$$
P_n(X) = n(p_g -1) + \sum_{i=1}^k n\left(1- \frac{1}{r_i}\right) + 1
$$

Now just use that $2K_X \sim 0$ implies $P_2(X)=1$.

Take a look at the corollaries of the canonical bundle formula in Dolgachev's paper "Algebraic surfaces with $p_g=q=0$".

Comment: Dear Alan, can you easily derive the first identity you wrote?

Comment: It's straightforward from $P_2(X) =1$.

Comment: :) yes but I meant if it was possible to derive it easily without using the second (more general) formula

Comment: Ah... Ok!. I don't think so. You can try to manipulate the canonical bundle formula, use that $F \sim r_i F_i$... But I think that, meanwhile, you will prove the second identity.

Comment: I see, thank you Alan. Then I'll go through the whole proof. (and thank you very much for Dolgachev's reference!!)

Comment: http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-11087-0_3
A link to the paper...